# OpenMP task dependencies to thread-private storages

Tags: multithreading, task, buffer, openmp

Considering the following example, OpenMP requires that the addresses stored in `buff1` and `buff2` must be determined. However, the addresses stored in `buff1` and `buff2` are determined according to the id (`myid`) of the thread that runs the task. How can I solve my problem? Any solution is appreciated. I am not allowed to allocate memory.

```c
mystruct* buff1;
mystruct* buff2;
#pragma omp task depend(in: data[0:1000]) depend(inout: buff1[0:0])
{
  int myid=omp_get_thread_num();
  buff1=buffers[myid];
  processA(data, buff1);
}
#pragma omp task depend(in: data[0:1000]) depend(inout: buff2[0:0])
{
  int myid=omp_get_thread_num();
  buff2=buffers[myid];
  processB(data, buff2);
}
#pragma omp task depend(in: data[0:1000]) depend(inout: buff1[0:0])  depend(inout: buff2[0:0])
{
  processC(data, buff1, buff2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Task dependences are registered when tasks are created. Note that they have to be fulfilled before starting the execution of the task, so what you are asking for is not possible.

Have you considered defining the dependences over `buff1` and `buff2` directly rather than over the content they point to?

```c
mystruct* buff1;
mystruct* buff2;
#pragma omp task depend(in: data[0:1000]) depend(inout: buff1) shared(buff1)
{
  int myid=omp_get_thread_num();
  buff1=buffers[myid];
  processA(data, buff1);
}
#pragma omp task depend(in: data[0:1000]) depend(inout: buff2) shared(buff2)
{
  int myid=omp_get_thread_num();
  buff2=buffers[myid];
  processB(data, buff2);
}
#pragma omp task depend(in: data[0:1000]) depend(inout: buff1, buff2) // shared(buff1, buff2) ???
{
  processC(data, buff1, buff2);
}
```

It's important to note the difference of meaning of these two clauses: `depend(inout: buff1)` and `depend(inout: buff1[0:0])`. The first one defines the dependence over `&buff1` whereas the second one defines the dependence over `&buff1[0] = &(*(buff1 + 0)) = buff1`. In general, the first one is used when the task is producing the value of the pointer itself (and it's usually used together with a `shared` clause) whereas the second one is used when the task is modifying the data pointed by that pointer.

Finally, you didn't specify the data-sharings of `buff1` and `buff2` variables. If the changes that your tasks do to these variables have to be visible from outside them, you have to annotate these variables as shared.